# Parsing XML using java DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

Im new in Java, and i have a task to Parse one xml file using http with current url http://belbooner.site40.net/testXmls/details.xml

I created Some class to parse it using Dom method, but im having java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to get one Nodes value 
So here's the code

```
import java.security.KeyStore.Builder;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.xml.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class RequestResponse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        URL url = new URL("http://belbooner.site40.net/testXmls/details.xml");
        RequestResponse req= new RequestResponse();
        req.getHTTPXml(url);
    }

     void getHTTPXml(URL url) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

                //URL url = new URL("http://belbooner.site40.net/testXmls/details.xml");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT","application/xml");
                InputStream xml = conn.getInputStream();


                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(xml);

                System.out.println(document);
                String doctype = conn.getContentType(); 
                System.out.print(doctype);

                NodeList root = document.getChildNodes();

                Node server = getNodes("server",root);
                Node check = getNodes("check", server.getChildNodes());
                NodeList nodes = check.getChildNodes();

                String checkid= getNodeValue("checkid", nodes);
                System.out.println(checkid);


                conn.disconnect();  

                //return (Document) DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xml);


     }


    Node getNodes(String tagName, NodeList nodes) {
        for(int i=0; i< nodes.getLength();i++) {
            Node node= nodes.item(i);
            if(node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)) {
                return node;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    String getNodeValue(String tagName, NodeList nodes ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++ ) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)) {
                NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
                for (int y = 0; y < childNodes.getLength(); y++ ) {
                     Node data = childNodes.item(y);
                     if ( data.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE ) {
                         return data.getNodeValue();
                     }
                     if(data instanceof CharacterData) {
                         CharacterData cd= (CharacterData) data;
                         return cd.getData();
                     }
                 }

            }
        }
        return "";
    }








    }
```

The stacktrace I'm getting is the following:

```
application/xmlException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
RequestResponse.getHTTPXml(RequestResponse.java:45) at
RequestResponse.main(RequestResponse.java:22)
```

After changin `Node server = getNodes("server",root);` to `

```
    Node resultNode = getNodes("result", root);
    Node server = getNodes("server", resultNode.getChildNodes());`

   `application/xmlException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at RequestResponse.getHTTPXml(RequestResponse.java:49)
        at RequestResponse.main(RequestResponse.java:22)

`
```

Please help me to find the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the stacktrace of the NullPointerException in the question.

Comment: could you share the line where you are getting the null pointer

Comment: application/xmlException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at RequestResponse.getHTTPXml(RequestResponse.java:45)
 at RequestResponse.main(RequestResponse.java:22)

Comment: Please print the error stack trace

Comment: @Arshak92 : I've edited the post for you to add the stacktrace to the question and also answered you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Node server = getNodes("server",root);` is returning null.

Why does this happen? Well look how you implemented getNodes

```
Node getNodes(String tagName, NodeList nodes) {
    for(int i=0; i< nodes.getLength();i++) {
        Node node= nodes.item(i);
        if(node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You are giving as input the document root which is a single "Result" node, you iterate through it and you compare if the node's name is in this case "server" which never will be, hence you return null and get a NPE.

Your node look up must be done in the following way:

```
 NodeList root = document.getChildNodes();
// Keep in mind that you have the following structure:
// result
//   server
//    checks
//     check
//      checkId
//     check
//      checkId

Node resultNode = getNodes("result", root);
Node server = getNodes("server", resultNode.getChildNodes());
Node checks = getNodes("checks", server.getChildNodes());
NodeList childNodes = checks.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node possibleCheck = childNodes.item(i);
    if (possibleCheck.getNodeName().equals("check")) {
    String checkid = getNodeValue("checkid", possibleCheck.getChildNodes());
    System.out.println(checkid);
    }
}
```

This way you'll be iterating through the correct node list.

Comment: I cant change to `root.getChildNodes() as its not a proper Node, maybe you wanted to say NodeList`
As you see there is another NodeList called root, and i cant take NodeList from NodeList

Comment: @Arshak92: you're right, sorry, I was seeing root has a "Node".  I've editted my answer

Comment: Thank you, but im having another exception 
`application/xmlException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at RequestResponse.getHTTPXml(RequestResponse.java:48)
 at RequestResponse.main(RequestResponse.java:22)`

Comment: I think the problem is in the method getNodes that causing such exception, I'll focus on it

Comment: @Arshak92: re-edit your question to add the updated coded along with the updated exception so I or any other stackoverflow member can help you. Also you should unaccept my answer until I've fully helped you.

Comment: @Arshak92: most probably you're error is in getNodes("check", server.getChildNodes()); the node name is "checks" not "check"

Comment: @Arshak92: I've edited the post to show you how you should have done all the node look up. Can you see that you were directly going to "check" nodes before going through the "checks" node?

Answer (score 2):

Using XPath is more efficient and flexible (than normal iteration) while parsing xml.

[XPath Tutorial from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html) 
[XPath Reference Orielly tutorial](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/12/xpath.html)  
[Xpath Reference Oracle java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html)

Try below code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class RequestResponse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
            IOException, SAXException {
        URL url = new URL("http://belbooner.site40.net/testXmls/details.xml");
        RequestResponse req = new RequestResponse();
        req.getHTTPXml(url);
    }

    void getHTTPXml(URL url) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException,
            SAXException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT", "application/xml");
        InputStream xml = conn.getInputStream();

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(xml);

        System.out.println(document);
        String doctype = conn.getContentType();
        System.out.println(doctype);

        XPathFactory pathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath path = pathFactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expression;
        try {
            expression = path.compile("/result/server/checks/check/checkid");
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(document,
                    XPathConstants.NODESET);

            String checkids[] = getNodeValue(nodeList);
            for (String checkid : checkids) {
                System.out.print(checkid + ", ");
            }

        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.disconnect();

    }

    String[] getNodeValue(NodeList nodes) {
        String checkIds[] = new String[nodes.getLength()];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            checkIds[i] = node.getTextContent();
        }
        return checkIds;
    }

}
```